# Relative Python Path to Script

Tags: python, relative-path

Python project looks like this:

```
setup.py
README
Application
    scripts
        hello.py
    shell_scripts
        date.sh
```

From `hello.py` I'm executing the command `subprocess.call(['../shell_scripts/date.sh'])` and receiving the error `OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error`.

Note: `date.sh` is a perfectly valid shell script and is executable. I've also tried `os.path.realpath` to no avail.

I assume this is due to an invalid path?

Comment: Is date.sh a valid shell Script? Do you have the she-bang line, path to the shell at the beginning of the script? Is the script executable?

Comment: It's executable and valid. Path to the shell?

Comment: @malcmcmul: The error proves you wrong. Did you try executing it from a shell?

Comment: Judging by your inkling that the shell isn't valid, are you saying the path is? I can execute it from my terminal (I'm putty'd into it) and it'll happily run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exec format error will come when the shell isn't set at the script. try adding `#!/bin/sh` at the beginning of the script and execute the python script.